# Strange behaviour when `RAISE LOG ...` is executed with interpolated value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

Recently had a script that failed on Postgres v13 ran but successfully ran on v14.
I believe the behaviour in v14 to be strange and potentially a bug, but wanted to check here before submitting a bug report.

- v13

  - PostgreSQL 13.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
- v14

  - PostgreSQL 14.6 on aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit

The offending code was this inside of a function:

```sql
RAISE LOG 'Foo %', 'Bar'

DELETE FROM barfoo ...;
```

Note the missing trailing `;` after the `RAISE LOG ...`.

In v13 when trying to run this it raises the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE"
LINE dd: DELETE FROM barfoo ...;
             ^ 
SQL state: 42601
Character: ddd
```

Which is the behaviour I would have expected.

When running on v14 there is no raised error, and the code appears to complete normally.

When trying to reproduce this I came up with the following code:

```sql
set client_min_messages = 'log';

drop table if exists error_test_tt;
create temp table error_test_tt as (
    select 1 as val
    union
    select 2
);

do $$
begin
    raise log 'test %', '01'
    
    delete from error_test_tt where val = 1;
end
$$;
select * from error_test_tt;
```

The log `test 01` is successfully logged, and the `delete ...` statement appears to be ignored.
The final `select * from error_test_tt` shows rows with val `1`, and `2`, meaning nothing was deleted.

Furthermore, the script *will* fail if the `RAISE LOG ...` is not using an interpolated value, i.e.:

```sql
RAISE LOG 'test 01'

delete from error_test_tt where val = 1;
```

Reading the documentation, I don't see any reason for this behaviour:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Is this a bug?

Comment: I can reproduce this in Postgres 15, as well. And I doesn't make sense. `RAISE` takes a variable number of parameters depending on the number of placeholders (`%`) in the format string. And it supports a variety of syntax variants. Might be a parser bug.  Please go ahead an file a bug report.

Comment: I'd expect `raise log 'test %', '01'`  to give an error as well - the semicolon is missed , but somehow placeholder + some text + reserved word doesn't give an error .  I tried different log levels as well - the same behaviour.   `raise log 'test %', '01' insert;`  `raise log 'test %', '01' truncate;` - go through :-)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue - have submitted a bug report!

Comment: This is as designed and documented, see https://postgr.es/m/2261324.1694292880%40sss.pgh.pa.us .